# Dúvida com com Script - Mostrar imagem de acordo com Seleção

Tags: javascript, html, script

Estou tentando fazer um select que mude a imagem de acordo com o selecionado, porém tenho dois tipos de select com suas respectivas imagens que devem aparecer de acordo com a seleção.
O problema é que ou eu faço com que ambos os select troquem a imagem de um só tipo de select eu faço ambos os select trocarem os dois tipos de imagem.
Gostaria que cada select trocasse respectivamente a sua imagem.
Como posso fazer isso?

Meu codigo:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
/* URL of folder with images  */
var baseURL_OF_images = "./";
/* array of default image files */
var images =
      [ "bronze.png", "prata.png",
        "gold.png", "platina.png",
        "diamante.png" ]
function switchImage(imgNum){
  var x = parseInt(imgNum);
  var src = baseURL_OF_images
                + ( ( x < 0 ) ? "bronze.png": images[x] );
  document.getElementById("#AvatarImage").src = src;
  document.getElementById("#AvatarImage2").src = src;
  return true;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="#AvatarImage" name="#AvatarImage" src="bronze.png" style="widht:200px;height:200px;"/>
<select id="#AvatarImage" onChange="switchImage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
  <option value="-1" selected="0">Bronze</option>
  <option value="1">Prata</option>
  <option value="2">Ouro</option>
  <option value="3">Platina</option>
  <option value="4">Diamante</option>

</select>

<img id="#AvatarImage2" name="#AvatarImage2" src="bronze.png" style="widht:200px;height:200px;"/>
<select id="#AvatarImage2" onChange="switchImage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
  <option value="-1" selected="0">Bronze</option>
  <option value="1">Prata</option>
  <option value="2">Ouro</option>
  <option value="3">Platina</option>
  <option value="4">Diamante</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode enviar na função como argumento qual será o target.
Cada tag deverá ter o seu id, por isso tabem alterei os ids.
Fica assim.:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
/* URL of folder with images  */
var baseURL_OF_images = "./";
/* array of default image files */
var images =
      [ "bronze.png", "prata.png",
        "gold.png", "platina.png",
        "diamante.png" ]
function switchImage(imgNum,target){
  var x = parseInt(imgNum);
  var src = baseURL_OF_images
                + ( ( x < 0 ) ? "bronze.png": images[x] );
  document.getElementById("AvatarImage"+target).src = src;
  //document.getElementById("#AvatarImage2").src = src; Não é mais necessário
  return true;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="AvatarImage" name="AvatarImage" src="bronze.png" style="widht:200px;height:200px;"/>
<select id="SelectAvatarImage" onChange="switchImage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'');">
  <option value="-1" selected="0">Bronze</option>
  <option value="1">Prata</option>
  <option value="2">Ouro</option>
  <option value="3">Platina</option>
  <option value="4">Diamante</option>

</select>

<img id="AvatarImage2" name="#AvatarImage2" src="bronze.png" style="widht:200px;height:200px;"/>
<select id="SelectAvatarImage2" onChange="switchImage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,2);">
  <option value="-1" selected="0">Bronze</option>
  <option value="1">Prata</option>
  <option value="2">Ouro</option>
  <option value="3">Platina</option>
  <option value="4">Diamante</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tudo ok amigo, obrigado pela ajuda!

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
/* URL of folder with images  */
var baseURL_OF_images = "./";
/* array of default image files */
var images =
      [ "bronze.png", "prata.png",
        "gold.png", "platina.png",
        "diamante.png" ]
function switchImage(imgNum,target){
  var x = parseInt(imgNum);
  var src = baseURL_OF_images
                + ( ( x < 0 ) ? "bronze.png": images[x] );
  document.getElementById("AvatarImage"+target).src = src;
  //document.getElementById("#AvatarImage2").src = src; Não é mais necessário
  return true;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<img id="AvatarImage" name="AvatarImage" src="bronze.png" style="widht:200px;height:200px;"/>
<select id="SelectAvatarImage" onChange="switchImage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'');">
  <option value="-1" selected="0">Bronze</option>
  <option value="1">Prata</option>
  <option value="2">Ouro</option>
  <option value="3">Platina</option>
  <option value="4">Diamante</option>

</select>

<img id="AvatarImage2" name="#AvatarImage2" src="bronze.png" style="widht:200px;height:200px;"/>
<select id="SelectAvatarImage2" onChange="switchImage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,2);">
  <option value="-1" selected="0">Bronze</option>
  <option value="1">Prata</option>
  <option value="2">Ouro</option>
  <option value="3">Platina</option>
  <option value="4">Diamante</option>

</select>
```